# default type conversions from sub to supertype, zero parameter functions

Tags: scala, types

I am trying to understand the mechanism with which scala implements  default type converions from sub to super type in scala.Predef. From the literature I gathered that this is done with the function

```
implicit def conforms[A] = new A<:<A { def apply(a:A)=a }
```

The parameterless function conforms[A] returns the implicit conversion A=>B as its only 
function value (as a callable of type A=>A and thus of type A=>B, whenver A<:B).

However when the compiler looks for an implicit type conversion it needs an implicit value
of type A=>B not a function returning such a value. Thus my question:

When looking for a default type conversion from A=>B, where A<:B, how does the compiler
get from the function conforms[A] to its unique value.

Comment: No, it does not compile. You cannot override a `val` with a `def`

Comment: @Dima OK, thanks. IntelliJ did not flag it immediately and I did not do a build. I will remove it from the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implicit resolution seeks for subtypes too, `A <: B` => `A => A <: A => B`, as in `List[Int] <: Seq[Int]`.

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

implicit val x: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
def f(implicit x: Seq[Int]): Int = x.head
f

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

x: Seq[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
f: (implicit x: Seq[Int])Int
res1: Int = 1
```

So when making type conversion we look for `A => B` with `A <: B`, and `A => A` fits.

---

I'm not sure if I understood you right, but the `defs` are followed while searching for value of the needed type. It doesn't matter whether function takes zero, one, or more parameters. For example with zero:

```
implicit def implicitList[A]: List[A] = List() //the only obvious case
scala> implicitly[Seq[Int]]
// res0: Seq[Int] = List()
```

Or two:

```
case class Foo(str: String)
case class Bar(str: String)
case class Quux(str: String)

implicit val foo = Foo("foo")
implicit val bar = Bar("bar")

// how to build quux:
implicit def quux(implicit foo: Foo, bar: Bar): Quux = Quux(foo.str + bar.str)

implicitly[Quux]
// res2: Quux = Quux(foobar)
```

If we add any of:

```
implicit def quux2(implicit quux: Quux): Quux = quux
implicit def quux3(implicit foo: Foo): Quux = Quux(foo.str)
implicit val quux4: Quux = Quux("quux")
implicit def quux5[A]: Quux = Quux("poly")
```

We make implicit resolution undecidable for `Quux`:

```
scala> implicitly[Quux]
<console>:29: error: ambiguous implicit values:
 both method quux of type (implicit foo: Foo, implicit bar: Bar)Quux
 and method quux2 of type (implicit quux: Quux)Quux
 match expected type Quux
              implicitly[Quux]
                    ^
```

I.e. there could be only one `def` or `val` in scope *returning* the type we are interested. And that is easy to verify statically.

But they will work if any of those is the only one in scope.

Comment: The point is: it looks for a _value_ of type A=>B but finds a zero parameter function returning such a value. So the issue is under which conditions a zero parameter function can be substituted for its value. At least if I understand the process correctly.

Comment: @michaelmeyer I amended the answer. Hopefully now I answer the right question.